# Ag-Grid: "paste from clipboard" not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, ag-grid, clipboard, navigator

I'm struggling to make sense of the [Clipboard](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/documentation/javascript/clipboard/) feature of Ag-Grid. Currently, when trying to use it in Firefox (via any of the examples on the linked page), I'm getting the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: navigator.clipboard.readText is not a function
    pasteFromClipboard https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/dev/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js:80812
    onCtrlAndV https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/dev/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js:31893
    doGridOperations https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/dev/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js:31758
    processKeyboardEvent https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/25.0.0/dev/@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules/dist/ag-grid-enterprise.js:31720
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/readText), this method is indeed unavailable to the ordinary pages in Firefox - only to the extensions. Is there any known workaround for this issue?

Comment: you can use the old method of executing `copy` on a selected hidden input field. 
https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_copy_clipboard.asp